# Reputation shows twice for one post (before and after editing)

Tags: bug, reputation, ios-app

Using the iOS app, I was checking my achievements, and it showed the reputation from the same [answer](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/a/31320/419) twice. Once before the edit of the parent post's title, and the other text from after. See the screenshot. I (of course) was awarded just the 50 rep from the 5 upvotes.

[image]

Having no issues using the website.

[image]

Comment: Yeah, this happens time to time when you edit the question under a new title so the app has both versions under Achievements. It's probably caching, no biggie. Refresh and it goes away.

Comment: @AndrewLi must be some cache. Been refreshing since the post was edited, and it's still going. I know it doesn't really hurt anything, but if it doesn't need to be like that, it should be fixed